# generar tests dinámicos en cypress desde una base de datos

Tags: javascript, pruebas-unitarias, cypress

Estoy intentado generar test dinámicos en cypress a partir del resultado de una base de datos.

Dependiendo del usuario utilizado voy a tener que comprobar el contenido de diferentes tarjetas. La cosa es que tanto el número de tarjetas como su contenido varia y estos datos se encuentran en una base de datos.

La conexión a base de datos funciona bien y si genero las pruebas de forma estática funciona sin problemas, pero quería poder crearlas de forma dinámica para agrupar los tests del contenido de cada tarjeta y así poder ver de forma diferenciada si ha fallado en alguna tarjeta específica.

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
var url = require("../../../../../Repositorio/sessions/urls.json")
var users = require("../../../../../Repositorio/jdd/users.json")

context('Test', () => {
  let tUser = [];
  let tCards = [];

  before(() => {
    cy.task('connectDb', `SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE email='${users.testEmailUser.user}'`).then(result => {
      result.forEach(user => {
        tUser.push(user)
      })

      return cy.task('connectDb', `SELECT * FROM public."cardTable" WHERE "idUser"='${tUser[0].id}'`).then(result => {
          tCards = result
      })
    })
  })

  beforeEach( function () {
    cy.visit('')
  })

  describe('Cards', () => {
    tCards.forEach((card, index) => {
      it(`Card ${index}`, () => {
        cy.log("object:", card);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

Y el error que devuelve la terminal de cypress:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]